# Swiper JS, swiper.destroy() doesnt work and I cant find the issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiper JS and can't find a way to destroy the swiper when needed and using the function with $(window).resize()
Please tell me what can be the issue.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 initTopInfoContainerSwiper()
}

$(window).resize(() => {
 initTopInfoContainerSwiper()
}

let swiperInitParam = true;
let swiperDestroyParam = false;

const initTopInfoContainerSwiper = () => {
  const swiper = new Swiper('#js__swipper-top-wrapper-index', {
    init: false,
    speed: 400,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centerInsufficientSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 15,
    loop: true,
  });

  if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
    if (swiperInitParam) {
      swiper.init();
      swiperInitParam = false;
      swiperDestroyParam = true;
    }
  } 
  else {
    if (swiperDestroyParam) {
      swiper.destroy()
      swiperDestroyParam = false;
      swiperInitParam = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to all of this methods but none worked

```js
if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
  if (swiperInitParam) {
    swiper.init();
    swiper.enable();
    swiperInitParam = false;
    swiperDestroyParam = true;
  }
} 
else {
  if (swiperDestroyParam) {
    swiper.loop = false;
    swiper.allowTouchMove = false;
    swiper.enable = false;
    swiper.enabled = false;
    swiper.disable = true;
    swiper.disabled = true;
    swiper.allowClick = false;
    swiper.allowSlidePrev = false;
    swiper.allowSlideNext = false;
    swiper.allowClick = false;
    swiper.initialized = false;
    swiper.init()
    swiperDestroyParam = false;
    swiperInitParam = true;
  }
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are calling `initTopInfoContainerSwiper()` on every resize. That is not a good option when you probalby just want to listen to a specific viewport width. Instead you could do something like this:

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 1000px)`)
mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', () => {
  initSwiper()
})
```

To destroy the swiper, you can simply say

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
   swiper.init();
} 
else {
   swiper.destroy(true, true)
}
```

(see [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-destroy) for more information).

And i also think there is no need for `swiperInitParam` and `swiperDestroyParam` unless you are accessing them somewhere else.